# ASP.NET как основа для сайта и мобильного приложения

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, asp.net, mobile

Есть идея веб и мобильного приложения. Для кроссплатформенной разработки под мобильные устройства будет использоваться C#+Xamarin. Теперь вопрос с сайтом, БД одна на все платформы, а можно ли написать и всю логику на все платформы, включая сайт? Все обращения к БД реализовать через API, например. По производительности как лучше, в мобильном приложении одна логика, для сайта другая и одна БД, или через API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте WCF, благо Xamarin позволяет использовать WCF. А конкретно есть WCF DS готовый сервис для работы с БД.

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/walkthrough_working_with_WCF/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/odata.aspx

И сайт и приложения будут использовать один сервис.

Answer (score 0):

конечно можно 
вот пример - то что видит юзер на сайте 
[link text](http://xn----7sbab9byagn3e.xn--p1ai/OfInfo/)
и то что отдается по Api для приложения в ГУГЛЕ 
[link text](http://xn----7sbab9byagn3e.xn--p1ai/api/ofinfo)

реализация

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;

public class InfoController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/<controller>

    public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        List<InfoDetails> detailsInfo = new List<InfoDetails>();
        string con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["..."].ToString();
        string query = "SELECT TOP (30) id, title, text, date FROM ... ORDER BY date DESC";
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(con))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select max(id) from ...", conn))
            {
                int lastId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

                if (lastId >= id && lastId - id < 50)
                {
                    query = "select id, title, text, Date from ... where id >" + id + " order By Date DESC";
                }

                using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
                {
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    foreach (DataRow dtrow in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        InfoDetails info = new InfoDetails();
                        info.Id = Convert.ToInt32(dtrow["id"].ToString());
                        info.Title = dtrow["title"].ToString();
                        info.Text = dtrow["text"].ToString();
                        info.Date = dtrow["Date"].ToString();
                        detailsInfo.Add(info);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return new HttpResponseMessage() { Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(detailsInfo.ToArray()), Encoding.UTF8, "text/json") };
    }
    public class InfoDetails
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; }
    }
}
```